# flex-box hover child full height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to do a grid caret, the caret will be on top and bottom, and when user hover on each side there will be a grey area.

```
<div class="control-wrap">
  <div class="caret-wrap">
    <span class="caret">▲</span>
  </div>

  <div class="caret-wrap">
    <span class="caret">▼</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My progress is good but there's an issue with the hover, it doesn't fill the rest of the space around.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/xqq0wpes/1/

Comment: Have a look - https://jsfiddle.net/rdoqgrur/ is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

With a little modification - on the `.control-wrap` just manage the flow of the child elements (`.caret-wrap`), and on the child elements(`.caret-wrap`) control the caret's position.

```css
.control-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.caret-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;

  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.caret-wrap:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.caret-wrap:active {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-wrap">
  <div class="caret-wrap">
    <span class="caret">▲</span>
  </div>

  <div class="caret-wrap">
    <span class="caret">▼</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqq0wpes/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: space-evenly;` from the `.control-wrap` and add `flex: 1 1 auto;`, `align-items: center;`, `justify-content: center;` to the `.caret-wrap` so that child item get the full width and available height and caret will get aligned in the center. Here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xqq0wpes/10/

Here is your updated CSS

```
.control-wrap {
  width: 20px;
  /* align-items: center; */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
  /* justify-content: space-evenly; */
  .caret-wrap {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    &:hover {
      background: #ddd;
    }
    &:active {
      color: grey;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need of **Flexbox** here...You can do it without flexbox.

Also for symbols try to use html entities here instead of direct symbol

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.control-wrap {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}

.caret-wrap {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8px;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  background: red;
}

.caret-wrap:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.caret-wrap:active {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-wrap">
  <div class="caret-wrap">
    <span class="caret">&#9650;</span>
  </div>

  <div class="caret-wrap">
    <span class="caret">&#9660;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```